# Is there an url to click a tab in a MVC app?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I use an editor (from a 3rd party vendor) that allows the users of my MVC App to create/edit Html pages and to include links and images as well. If a link is inserted in the document, it opens a custom dialog and prompt for an url, for example, "http://stackoverflow.com". I would like to know if it is possible on this link, to enter an url that would instead select (click) a tab in the app, in this case it would be the one bellow:

```
<li><a href="#tabLocations" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Locations</a></li>
```

Comment: A downvote without any comment or explanation. So useless....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably wouldn't be possible given the constraints of your editor, if it only allows you to enter a URL for the link. You could try entering #tabLocations as the url, but without the ability to add Javascript (either inline or via an onclick attribute) this is not possible. Your question was downvoted most likely because there are some ambiguities (what is this editor you are talking about?)